# Не выполняется ограничение CHECK в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Создал таблицу с ограничениями:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
TaskID INTEGER CHECK (TaskID > 0),
Task VARCHAR(100),
TaskStart DATE,
TaskEnd DATE CHECK (TaskEnd > TaskStart),
TaskStatus VARCHAR(10) CHECK (TaskStatus in ('Done', 'Not Done'))
);
```

Потом ввел недопустимое значение, но ограничение его пропустило:

```
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES
(1, 'Нормализовать базу данных', DATE('2023-12-16'), DATE('2023-12-17'), 'Unknown')
```

Почему так?

Comment: А версия MySQL - какая? Нужна 8.0.16 или новее

Comment: 5.7.4, судя по запросу SELECT @@VERSION

Comment: *Prior to MySQL 8.0.16, CREATE TABLE permits only the following limited version of table CHECK constraint syntax, which is parsed **and ignored***

Comment: а зачем вам строка с чеком а не enum ?